# Detect when user wants to open the in a new window/tab

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas

I'm writing an AJAX application so every link on my page is a javascript link (`href="javascript:void(blahblah)"`). Some of them opens small webpages in an iframe in a boxed, absolutely positioned div element (that can be dragged around).

This looks nice but if the user middle click on the link he can't open the page in a new tab, because the browser tries to execute the script on a new page which fails.

So what I want to do is:

- If the user clicks on the link it opens a webpage in an iframe in an absolutely positioned div. (this works currently).
- If the user middle clicks these links (or somehow opens the link in a new tab/window etc.) the page should load in the new tab/window as expected.
- Optional: middle click should do nothing on all other javascript links.

Is there a (preferably cross browser) way to accomplish this?

EDIT: this web app is a browser game which uses the canvas element to render the game world, so I don't mind if your solution works only in canvas-capable browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a (preferably cross browser) way to accomplish this?

Yes, don't do `href="javascript:void(blahblah)"`, [build on things that work.](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **hijax** technique, which allows you to [progressively enhance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) your application to use either regular or JavaScript links.  There's an [hijax jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hijax) that can help.